# :include searches with the wrong value

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a number of models in a Rails project that are linked to a user, and I'm running into a loading problem I try to get all of the user's data displayed on a page.

My model declarations look sort of like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :server_user_id
  has_many :setup_notes, :foreign_key => "server_user_id"
  has_many :closure_votes, :foreign_key => "user_id"
end

class SetupNote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => "server_user_id"
end
```

I should note that in the SQL table for closure votes, `user_id` is the same value as `server_user_id` in the table for users.

When I try using the `:include` symbol in a Rails query, it ends up using `user.id` for the search value when I need to find closure votes and setup notes through `user.server_user_id`.  In other words,

```
me = User.first(:conditions => ["server_user_id = ?", 12610], :include => :setup_notes)
```

generates the MySQL query

```
SELECT `setup_notes`.* FROM `setup_notes` WHERE (`setup_notes`.server_user_id = 1)
```

Which returns an empty set.  Is there any way to format the Rails query/models to send the relevant SQL query, or do I need to write a raw query for all of the models associated with the users (and if that's the case, how do I do that?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly (that User has a `server_user_id` field), in the User model you have to set the :primary_key option like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :server_user_id
  has_many :setup_notes, :foreign_key => "server_user_id", :primary_key => "server_user_id"
  has_many :closure_votes, :foreign_key => "user_id", :primary_key => "server_user_id"
end
```

Comment: Thank you!  Absolutely none of the Rails resources I've looked at even hinted that was possible.